# Need help implementing my movement with left down right and up arrow keys for 15 puzzle game

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am having issues learning the movement for my 15 puzzle game.  I need the blank tile to be able to move left right up and down unless it's touching the sides of course.  I have some of the code on hand but I need help with my movement and ideas for implementing a game over state, maybe by restarting the game if not completed in time was my idea, but I was oblivious on how to start.

For now, I need help with the movement and only using the techniques I have been applying to my code.  No jQuery or anything like that.  Just basic, java, html tables, and CSS to change the appearance but I can do that with no problem.  I am not a main coder and this is for homework, to be honest and I am not so Javascript friendly and I main in 3d modelling so you get an idea of expertise I am at.  Here is the code:

```js
 var bposr =3; // blank position : row
    var bposc=3;  // blank position : column


    function keypress() {
    var ieKey = event.keyCode;

    
       
            if (ieKey == 40 && bposr!=0){ // for moving down
            temp= 
    document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr1].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
          
    document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr1].cells[bposc
    ].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr
    ].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        
     document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc
    ].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
       document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr1
    ].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposr--;
       }

        else if (ieKey == 37 && bposc!=1){  // for moving right
            temp= 
     document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1
    ].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr
    ].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        
    document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc
    ].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
       document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1
    ].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposc++;
    
        }
        
     else if (ieKey == 39 && bposc!=1){  // for moving left
            temp= 
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1
        ].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr
        ].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr
        ].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc
        ].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc+1
        ].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposc++;
    
    }
        
    else if (ieKey == 38 && bposr!=0){ // for moving down
            temp= document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-
    1].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-
    1].cells[bposc].innerHTML=document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr
    ].cells[bposc].innerHTML;
        
    document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc].innerHTML=temp;
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr].cells[bposc
    ].style.backgroundColor='#DCDCDC';
        document.getElementById("myTable").rows[bposr-
    1].cells[bposc].style.backgroundColor='#ffffff';
        bposr--;
       }
        
       }

        function start(){
                    document.onkeydown = keypress;
                    }
```

```css
    table, td {
        border:  solid black;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #DCDCDC;
    } 

    td {
        width: 20px;
    
    }
```

```html
    <body onLoad="start()">
    <center>
    <table id="myTable">
  
  
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
      </tr>
  
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
      </tr>
  
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
      </tr>
  
      <tr>
       
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td style="background-color:white;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
```

Comment: *jQuery, *JavaScript. Please format your code, perhaps create a stack snippet. Limit your question to a single issue and remove unnecessary code. If you need ideas on how to improve your implementation / design, see the codereview stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, all I need help with is fixing the movement and explaining how it works.  I don't know stack overflow much how do you create a snippet?

Comment: You create a Snippet by clicking on the `<>` (snippet) button in the editor when typing the question. I've done it for you....

Comment: Maybe you could add a little more eases for you (and for us to understand) by creating javascript function like `move`. This code is repeated and I think can be easilly parameterized. For information, you can create function in another function in javascript (but it could be only call in the main function.)